# sparkjob fails with guava error-java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: apache-spark, guava, nosuchmethoderror

We have setup open source apache hadoop cluster with following below components.

```
hadoop - 3.1.4
spark - 3.3.1
hive - 3.1.3
```

When we are trying to run the spark example job with below command but it fails with the following exception.

```
/opt/spark-3.3.1/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --num-executors 1 --driver-memory 1G --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 1  /opt/spark-3.3.1/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.3.1.jar
```

**Error :**

```
[2022-12-09 00:05:02.747]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/hdfsdata2/yarn/local/usercache/spark/filecache/70/__spark_libs__3692263374412677830.zip/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop-3.1.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2022-12-09 00:05:02,137 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for TERM
2022-12-09 00:05:02,139 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for HUP
2022-12-09 00:05:02,139 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for INT
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1338)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.$anonfun$appendHiveConfigs$1(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:477)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.$anonfun$appendHiveConfigs$1$adapted(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:476)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.appendHiveConfigs(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:476)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkHadoopUtil$$appendS3AndSparkHadoopHiveConfigurations(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.newConfiguration(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:430)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
```

After debugging, this error seems to be related to guava and it's dependent jars.

Hadoop is having guava-27.0-jre.jar and spark is having guava-14.0-jre.jar.

I removed the spark guava jars and copied the guava and it's dependent jars from hadoop lib location to spark jars folder. Below are all list of guava and it's dependent jars.

```
/opt/spark-3.3.1/jars/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.17.jar
/opt/spark-3.3.1/jars/failureaccess-1.0.jar
/opt/spark-3.3.1/jars/error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.jar
/opt/spark-3.3.1/jars/checker-qual-2.5.2.jar
/opt/spark-3.3.1/jars/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar
/opt/spark-3.3.1/jars/jsr305-3.0.2.jar
/opt/spark-3.3.1/jars/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar
/opt/spark-3.3.1/jars/guava-27.0-jre.jar
```

But still the error seems to persist.

Interestingly, when I run the same example spark job as below **it succeeds.**

```
/opt/spark-3.3.1/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --num-executors 1 --driver-memory 1G --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 1  /opt/spark-3.3.1/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.3.1.jar 50
```

So the observation is any value less than 50 passed at the end of the command fails whereas higher value makes the job succeed. I am not sure about the reason behind this.

Comment: You are referring to JARs on one filesystem, compared to all of your YARN nodemanagers. I highly doubt the number argument matters. It's where the executor actually runs, where the classpath is causing the problem. For instance, did you repackage `spark.yarn.archives` with new Guava version?

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer , I made sure all the guava and dependency jars are on all node manager nodes even before I posted the error.

After your suggestion, I added below property in spark-default.conf along with restart of spark history server and tried running the spark job but it failed with the same guava exception.


spark.yarn.jars hdfs:///spark3-history/jars/*


Please advise.

Comment: @OneCricketeer ,

I even tried stopping all of nodemanagers except one out of 5 and then running the job, interestingly the same example job fails some times and succeeds sometimes.

`
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1357)
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1338)
`

and we can see that all guava and dependency jars are picked up by the container in spark history server UI.

Comment: I don't think you should be using the history server classpath for your jobs. It would be `spark.yarn.archives` that controls what gets unpacked on the classpath of each executor. There is another Hadoop config like `userClasspathFirst`, or similar that you can tell YARN to use your own app/jar classes before loading YARN's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Saurav Suman, To avoid this confusion of spark to find its hadoop yarn specific jars, Apache Spark documentation has provided a clean resolution.

If you have downloaded Spark without hadoop binaries and you have set up hadoop by yourself, then you should follow this below link and create your `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)`
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html

And this will take care of Spark picking up its hadoop related binaries. And I reckon spark does not come with its own Guava.
This above error particularly appears when either you are using outdated Guava or there are multiple Guava files that are conflicting which is not allowing Spark to decide which one to choose. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks , yes I am using spark without hadoop binary and after adding the SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH variable in spark-env.sh , my gurava and libraries issue got resolved.